# What the expectation of X given 2X?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am currently self studying  probability theory.

My question how would one compute  $E(X|2X)$ only knowing that X is an RV?

First attempt I tried to approach it using CE formula:

$E(X|2X)=\sum x\frac{P(X=x \cap 2X=y)}{P(2X=y)}=\sum x\frac{P(X=\frac{y}{2})}{
P(X=\frac{y}{2})}=\sum x$.

However the answer seem off so I tired using CE definition:
$E(X|2X)=E(X|\sigma(2X))=E(X|\sigma(X))=X$. 
But I am not sure if $\sigma(X) = \sigma(2X)$,  so I don’t if my answer is correct.

PS: I haven’t study measure theory before probability theory.

Comment: Your second approach is right; $E[X \mid 2X] = X$. It is true that $\sigma(X) = \sigma(2X)$; think about preimages $X^{-1}(B)$ and $(2X)^{-1}(B)$ for Borel sets $B$.

Comment: Assuming you know that $E[Z|Z]=Z$, then $E[X|2X] = \frac 12 E[2X|2X]  = \frac 12 2X = X$.

Comment: Thank @angryavian.